# To remove the double quotes from string in a file python

Tags: python, string

I have file where it consists some string values which is shown in `file1`. i wanted to remove some certain string values plus some characters from it and to write it to new `cleaned_file`. i have created list to remove those values present in it. To remove double quotes from string `"some_String"` in my list I am passing `" \""` which is not working. so what double quotes should be passed in my list

code.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

infile = "file1"
outfile = "cleaned_file.txt"

delete_list = ["value", " \"", ",", ":", " "]
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)
```

file1

```
                         "value": "Apple",
                         "value": "Mango",
                         "value": "Kiwi",
                         "value": "Strawberry",
                         "value": "Orange",
```

cleaned_file.txt

```
Apple
Mango
Kiwi
Strawberry
Orange
```

Comment: If your input file contained `[]` around that, it'd be JSON. Are you sure it isn't JSON? Because then you wouldn't need to do any of this replacing at all, you'd just need to parse it with a JSON parser and take the values from it that you need…

Comment: `" \""` shouldn't it be just `'"'` ?

Comment: @deceze no its not JSON

Comment: @MauriceMeyer that worked , i passed into my list as ' " '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file appears to be a JSON fragment of some kind.  We could use a regex approach to do the cleanup:

```
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = re.sub(r'^\s*"[^"]*":\s*"(.*?)".*$', r'\1', line)
    fout.write(line)
```

That being said, if you need to process a complete JSON file, you should look to *parse* it.  Python's native `json` library is pretty powerful for this.